# How can I hide property in list class

Tags: c#, list, class, json.net, generic-list

I have a question and realy need some solution. 
My class are below.

```
  public class Attributes
{
    public int attributeId { get; set; }
    public int ?attributeValueId { get; set; }
    public string customAttributeValue { get; set; }
}

public class Products
{
    public string barcode { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string productMainId { get; set; }
    public List<Attributes> attributes { get; set; }

}
```

I don't want it to visible Json is created when i can't assign a value to the **customAttributeValue** property.
Every time I get the output below.

**Every time I get the output below.**

```
 "attributes": [
  {
    "attributeId": 338,     
    "attributeValueId": 3961,
    "customAttributeValue": null
  },
  {
    "attributeId": 343,
    "attributeValueId": 4294,
    "customAttributeValue": null
  },
  {
    "attributeId": 47,
    "attributeValueId": 0,
    "customAttributeValue": "Black"
  }
]
```

**Iı need to send this type ..**

```
"attributes": [
    {
      "attributeId": 338,
      "attributeValueId": 6980
    },
    {
       "attributeId": 47,
       "customAttributeValue": "BLACK"
     },
    {
      "attributeId": 346,
      **attributeValueId": 4290**
```

Thank you for helping.

Comment: please refer this [link](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NullValueHandlingIgnore.htm)

Comment: Hi Tom , I use newtonsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
public class Vessel{
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Class { get; set; }

[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public DateTime? LaunchDate { get; set; }}

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vessel, Formatting.Indented);
```

and the output for

```
Vessel vessel = new Vessel{
Name = "Red October",
Class = "Typhoon"};
```

will be:

{
   "Name": "Red October",
   "Class": "Typhoon"
}

[JsonPropertyAttribute](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyPropertyLevelSetting.htm)

Answer (score 1):

As in the other answer which suggests using `JsonPropertyAttribute` is a good solution if you want this behaviour to happen only in this model.

```
public class Attributes
{
    public int attributeId { get; set; }
    public int ?attributeValueId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string customAttributeValue { get; set; }
}
```

Or if you just want this to happen in one case and avoid changing the model you can do this like:

```
string jsonOutput= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(instanceOfProduct, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
});
```

However if you want this behaviour to happen globally then you can set the JSON serialization settings in start up like this (.NET core 3.1 web app):

```
 services.AddMvc()
         .AddJsonOptions(options => {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;
 });
```

Comment: Tom , Tank you for everything. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Below sample uses the JsonIgnoreAttribute to exclude a property from serialization.

```
 [JsonIgnore]
public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
```

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PropertyJsonIgnore.htm

When you want to work only null values

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NullValueHandlingIgnore.htm

Comment: This will exclude a property from serialization completely irrespective of value

Comment: Yeah sorry i didn't notice the null contraint and you have already answered. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will check and inform. you

Comment: I tried but always return visible false. "[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]" This is  solved my problem.  Thanks anyway